# Skip unittest test without decorator syntax

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a suite of tests that I have loaded using TestLoader's (from the unittest module) loadTestsFromModule() method, i.e.,

```
suite = loader.loadTestsFromModule(module)
```

This gives me a perfectly ample list of tests that works fine. My problem is that the test harness I'm working with sometimes needs to skip certain tests based on various criteria. What I want to do is something like this:

```
for test in suite:
    mark the test as 'to-skip' if it meets certain criteria
```

Note that I can't just remove the test from the list of tests because I want the unittest test runner to actually skip the tests, add them to the skipped count, and all of that jazz.

The unittest documentation [suggests using decorators](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest-skipping) around the test methods or classes. Since I'm loading these tests from a module and determining to skip based on criteria not contained within the tests themselves, I can't really use decorators. Is there a way I can iterate over each individual test and some how mark it as a "to-skip" test without having to directly access the test class or methods within the class?

Comment: You might consider py.test, which has a [skipif](http://pytest.org/latest/skipping.html#marking-a-test-function-to-be-skipped)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using [`unittest.TestCase.skipTest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.skipTest):

```
import unittest

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self): print('setup')
    def tearDown(self): print('teardown')
    def test_spam(self): pass
    def test_egg(self): pass
    def test_ham(self): pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    loader = unittest.loader.defaultTestLoader
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)
    suite = loader.loadTestsFromModule(sys.modules['__main__'])
    for ts in suite:
        for t in ts:
            if t.id().endswith('am'): # To skip `test_spam` and `test_ham`
                setattr(t, 'setUp', lambda: t.skipTest('criteria'))
    runner.run(suite)
```

prints

```
test_egg (__main__.TestFoo) ... setup
teardown
ok
test_ham (__main__.TestFoo) ... skipped 'criteria'
test_spam (__main__.TestFoo) ... skipped 'criteria'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.001s

OK (skipped=2)


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.002s

OK (skipped=2)
```

**UPDATE**

Updated the code to patch `setUp` instead of test method. Otherwise, `setUp`/`tearDown` methods will be executed for test to be skipped.

**NOTE**

`unittest.TestCase.skipTest` (Test skipping) was introduced in Python *2.7, 3.1*. So this method only work in *Python 2.7+, 3.1+*.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit of a hack, but because you only need to raise `unittest.SkipTest` you can walk through your suite and modify each test to raise it for you instead of running the actual test code:

```
import unittest
from unittest import SkipTest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_this_should_skip(self):
        pass

    def test_this_should_get_skipped_too(self):
        pass

def _skip_test(reason):
    raise SkipTest(reason)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTestCase)
    for test in suite:
        skipped_test_method = lambda: _skip_test("reason")
        setattr(test, test._testMethodName, skipped_test_method)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

When I run this, this is the output I get:

```
test_this_should_get_skipped_too (__main__.MyTestCase) ... skipped 'reason'
test_this_should_skip (__main__.MyTestCase) ... skipped 'reason'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK (skipped=2)
```

Comment: `test_method` is not used; `test_method = getattr(test, test._testMethodName)` seems unnecessary.

Comment: `raise unittest.SkipTest(reason)` was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

Google brought me here.

I found the easiest way to do this is by raising a `SkipTest` exception when your skip criteria is met.

```
from unittest.case import SkipTest

def test_this_foo(self):
    if <skip conditsion>:
        raise SkipTest
```

And that test will be marked as skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Some observations:

- A test is a callable object with a `__call__(result)` method
- `TestCase` provides a higher-level interface, allowing test methods to throw a `SkipTest` exception to skip themselves
- The `skip` decorators do exactly this
- Skipped tests are recorded calling the [`TestResult.addSkip(test, reason)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult.addSkip) method.

So you just need to replace the to-be-skipped tests with a custom test that calls `addSkip`:

```
class Skipper(object):
    def __init__(self, test, reason):
        self.test = test
        self.reason = reason

    def __call__(self, result):
        result.addSkip(self.test, self.reason)
```